# how to make call and get response .svc service with raw xml data

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, xamarin.ios

I am creating xamarin ios application where I have to call a service and validate username and password from there.The Address of service url is [svc service link](http://pilat.brisbanepilots.com.au:6969/Service.svc).this service validate username and password.The Username,password and deviceToken sending in the form of Raw xml Url as-

```
 var sr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsd = \"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"> <SOAP-ENV:Body> <Login xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"> <username xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">" + userName_pass + "</username><password xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">" + passWord_pass + "</password><deviceToken xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">" + deviceToken11 + "</deviceToken></Login></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
```

and soap address is -

```
var soapaction = "http://tempuri.org/IMobileService/Login";
```

I have no idea how to do it.I have wasted whole day into it so please help me . Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Xamarin IOS service call](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/). It contains a walkthrough for calling a service from android and IOS.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have already studied it but not able to understand it.can u please give me step by step solution.

Comment: I suppose that documentation provides the complete steps for making a service call. Could you share which part of code you are facing issues with? I am quite new to monotouch.